# How to break down pug components into blocks etc

Tags: html, pug

So I have an index.html file as my base layout. However, how do I say extract a block of html and include this to my block.

I know extends copies the page, but I'll show you what I'm doing. Please let me know also if this is correct way of approaching the problem.

So I have this html, that I want to separate in to another file called header.pug and then place this inside index.html as below.

```
            div.header-content
                div.top-section
                    div.logo
                        img(src="assets/img/logo.svg")
                    div.menus
                        nav.social-menus 
                            a(href="http://facebook.com")
                                span.hide Facebook
                            a(href="http://twitter.com")
                                span.hide Twitter
                            a(href="http://instagram.com")
                                span.hide Instagram
                            a(href="http://youtube.com")
                                span.hide YouTube
                        div.title-bar(data-responsive-toggle="main-nav")
                            button.menu-icon(data-toggle="main-nav") 
                            div.title-bar-title Menu
                        nav.main-navigation#main-nav(data-animate="menu-in menu-out")
                            li
                                a(href="index.html") Home
                            li
                                a(href="about.html") About Us
                            li
                                a(href="#") Process
                            li
                                a(href="#") Menu
                            li
                                a(href="#") Gallery
                            li
                                a(href="#") Contact Us



html
head
    title Foundation CoffeeShop
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="./assets/css/app.css")
    script(src='/assets/js/jquery.js')
    script(src='/assets/js/foundation.js')
    script(src='/assets/js/app.js')
body
    header.site-header
        div.container
            block header
                div.bottom-section
                    block main
                        h1.slogan A new experience everyday
    footer.site-footer
        div.container
            div.footer-content
                div.footer-box
                    h3 Location
                    p Glasgow, Whisky Bond
                div.footer-box
                    h3 Reservations
                    p Call us on
                    p 0141 552 8888
                div.footer-box
                    h3 Opening Hours
                    p Mon-Fri, 6am - 9pm
                    p Sat, 10am - 9pm
                    p Sun, Closed
        p.copyright All rights reserved - The CoffeeShop 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, put extends instead of extend!